# WSO2 API Manager HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://public-ip:9443/services/RemoteAuthorizationManagerService]

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I was tested the API manager and Identity Server working together in my machine, every thing was working SSO and API calling
but when I moved it to the public server and configured every like was before except the changing the hostnames to public IP I faced this Problem when I try to login with API manager publisher

```
    [2016-02-02 09:54:14,661] INFO - HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to urlhttps://public-ip:9443/services/RemoteAuthorizationManagerService
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    wso2am | at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    wso2am | at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    wso2am | at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    wso2am | at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    wso2am | at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    wso2am | at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    wso2am | at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:625)
    wso2am | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    wso2am | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    wso2am | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    wso2am | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Comment: Have you open the relavent ports?

Comment: I am using Docker, so I separated the identity server and API manager in containers, I exposed only two ports 9443 for Identity server and 9444 for API Manager

Comment: @ZakariaAliOsman - Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: How did you solved this?